# Centos VirtManager Clone image - Device eth0 does not exist in libvirt

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, libvirt

I up the Centos image using VirtualBox ,clone image and convert it into Qcow2 format and tried up using Virt-manager. But i found interface not available in VM.

It displays

"Bringing up interface eth0: Device eth0 does not seems to be present,"

I also tried removing the presistance rules , chkconfig network on and rebooting VM.

But could not able to achieving the interface in VM.

Please advice me with any ideas.

Comment: Sorry, This issue was due to NIC Device model , Base machine NIC driver was e1000 and VM it was set as rtl8139. Beacuse of which eth ports are not displayed. 

Once i changed to correct e1000 driver. it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to NIC Device model ,

Base machine NIC driver was e1000 and VM it was set as rtl8139. Beacuse of which eth ports are not displayed.

Once i changed to correct e1000 driver. it works.

New learning. Things that can be added into checklist. :)